# How to View Full text of Top query in AWS RDS Postgres - performace insights

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using the Postgres database from AWS RDS. I want to see the full text of Top query in AWS RDS performance insights.

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.UsingDashboard.html#USER_PerfInsights.UsingDashboard.SQLTextLimit

As per the documentation, I've updated the track_activity_query_size to the max: 102400, have also tried rebooting the Postgres DB instance, still, it shows the same truncated <= 500 chars.
PS: my Postgres DB instance version is 12.5

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the PostgresSQL logs and search the half length queries in the latest logs wherein you will get the full length queries of the same.

Go to the "Logs & events" tab in the respective database from RDS console and download the log. Then search using some file editor to get the full length queries.